# Scale-In & Centre A Shape in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, alignment, viewbox

I have struggling forming the logic of centring an svg shape in SVG. The `viewBox` scale function is fine, however, I struggle with the centring of the shape using `viewBox`.

[Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vesuni/edit?js,output)

Here is the code:

```
// SCALE & CENTRE THE TEMPLATE ON SCREEN
const svg = document.getElementsByTagName( "svg" )[ 0 ];
const t = document.getElementsByClassName( "templateParent" )[ 0 ];
const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect(),
        svgW = svgRect.width,
        svgH = svgRect.height,
        svgX = svgRect.x,
        svgY = svgRect.y;
const aspectRatio = svgW / svgH;
const tRect = t.getBBox(),
        tW = tRect.width,
        tH = tRect.height,
        tX = tRect.x,
        tY = tRect.y;
const tmW = tW * 1.25,
        tmH = tH * 1.25,
        tmX = tX * 1.25,
        tmY = tY * 1.25;
const vbH = tmH,
        vbW = tmW * aspectRatio,
        vbX = tmX * aspectRatio,
        vbY = tmY;
```

Comment: I use this approach for more control. Store path positions in an array. Apply SVG center translate value to path element. Then multiple each position by the scale value whenever you want to scale. Then map each position to center - position. then redraw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to move/scale your path to center of the your svg try the following: (Note: browsers don't handle viewBox and svg width/height the same, therefore I typically use transforms on the elements)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload=fit()>
<div style=background:lime;width:600px;height;400px;>
 <svg width="600" height="400" >
  <path id=myPath d="M329.66,99.99l22.1,4H238.43c-1.5-4.3,17.3-85.4,17.3-85.4c1.7-11-10.12-83.7-10.12-83.7l22.1-4 1.405 30.583 61.010 0 1.405 -30.583z" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="blue" />
 </svg>
</div>

<script>
//---onload---
function fit()
{
 var bb=myPath.getBBox()
 var bbx=bb.x
 var bby=bb.y
 var bbw=bb.width
 var bbh=bb.height
 //---center of path---
 var cx=bbx+.5*bbw
 var cy=bby+.5*bbh

//---Use min of width/height create scale: ratio of desired width vs current width--
var height=400-20 ///--ie padding=20 px--
var scale=height/bbh
//---where to move it: center of svg---
var targetX=300
var targetY=200
//---move its center to target x,y ---
var transX=(-cx)*scale + targetX
var transY=(-cy)*scale + targetY
  myPath.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")scale("+scale+" "+scale+")")
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Francis, I actually want to move the viewbox to centre on the shape, just enough so that its virtually filling the screen (1.25 is the padding given).

Comment: I changed the answer to scale it and add padding

Comment: thanks Francis, I managed to solve it. I had to find the limiting factor (in this case was the height), find its relationship to width & divide by half for centring. Not tested your code but accepting it because... you have an svg logo avatar. :!

Comment: svg logo avatar... :)